# Code Igniter: This navigation logic in a controller or view?

Tags: codeigniter, navigation

I have a view called 'sub_nav' and it currently holds a multidimentional array of the links for each section. This view looks at the controller name to get the current section and then loops through the appropriate array set and outputs the links.

that works works but it feels like maybe I should create a controller just for the nav? and make sub_nav simpler but only outputing.... ? can anyone advice?

```
$controllerName = $this->router->class; 
$methodName = $this->router->method; 

$subLinks['about'] = array( 
                        'introduction'  => 'Introduction',
                        'people'        => 'Our People'
                    );

$subLinks['contact'] = array(   
                        'singapore'     => 'Singapore', 
                        'japan'         => 'Japan'
                    );

?>

<ul>
    <?php foreach($subLinks[$controllerName] as $link=>$linkName){ ?>

    <li <?php if($methodName == $link){ ?>class="on"<? } ?>><a href="<?php   echo base_url(); ?><?php echo $controllerName ?>/<?php echo $link ?>/"><?php echo   $linkName ?></a></li>

    <? } ?>
</ul>
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the content is a **static** array, I would put it in either:

- **A view file.** Controllers aren't the only place views can be loaded, there's nothing wrong with calling `$this->load->view()` from within another view file (your template). Just store the array *and* the view logic there.
- **A config file.** May sound strange, but it's a perfect place for static data like this. This way you won't have to constantly load the data in every load->view() call. Just load the config file in `MY_Controller` or something, and you have access to it anywhere. Then you can write a navigation view or library that will output whatever navigation array you send to it (in other words, don't do any html here - just data, then use for the config item in your view). I say to use a base controller because there's probably no need to autoload this data, for an AJAX request for instance. You won't always need it.

It definitely doesn't belong in a Controller, which is more for processing requests and data. A library is a more likely candidate. If the content was dynamic (from the database for example) then you'd definitely want to use a Model or Library, but in this case I would prefer a view file. It's not likely you'll be using the navigation array data anywhere else except your views.

In any case, HTML belongs in views whenever possible. If you only use the navigation array in views, only in one view, and it's not dynamic, just store it right there in the view file. Models and libraries should be reusable, storing static data there (that you'll probably need to update frequently) makes no sense to me, but I'd be willing to listen to opponents.

Comment: Right, so what I'm doing now isn't totally bad form?

Comment: Not at all. I think it's optimal. Why separate the data from the view logic if it's not dynamic and only used in that view? You're just making an array so it's easier to create html. Personally, I have a Navigation library that creates HTML from whatever nav array you throw at it, and I always define those arrays in views, and run `$this->navigation->create($my_nav_array)` immediately after.

Comment: You definitely want to check out using a Template library. I'm sure there's plenty of good ones out there that are all similar. I haven't used any because I have my own, and I won't bother sharing it because it's crazy customized. Just a suggestion, you'll get sick of calling `$this->load->view('header')` repeatedly very quickly.

Comment: Thanks, i was considering that but want to keep things super simple being a noob to CI. Perhaps this one: http://maestric.com/doc/php/codeigniter_template

Comment: I can highly recommend Smarty, it's brilliant with or without Codeigniter.

Comment: @gio: That library you linked to is probably a great place to start, no matter how noob. You'll have more issues trying to figure out you own template system at this point. I'd avoid Smarty, it has its place but is overkill for you at this point.

Comment: Cool, fyi I went with that simple, made a slight change to it and it's all I need for now. At present, I'm going to keep the nav arrays in the view files but I will investigate using a base controller like you mention W as I may need to add multi-language support.

Answer (score 0):

Depending where the data for the navigation comes from, I might give it a model of its own (if it comes from a database for example). As for the logic for choosing navigation to display, I would put that logic in a common base controller, either running it on all page loads or placing code for it in a method on the base controller, so those pages that need it can use it.

If your controllers use something like $this->data to hold the data to send to the view, then the base controller logic could pass the navigation data to the view too.

Comment: Thanks. all pages will use it and the data (arrays of links/link titles) is static - so I should just keep it in the controller? albeit putting this in a common base controller as you say

Comment: Yes, that would work fine. If you want to make it easier to extend in the future, you might want to put the array in a stub model anyway, but it would obviously be fine in the controller at present.

Comment: I see. One other Q (my first foray into CI), is it another legitimate option to put it into a library? I'm looking to do a very basic template class that wraps a header and footer around everything and the nav appears inside the header. So could all of this be in the template class/library? or is that not the done thing... thanks